# iPhone jack remote buttons wiring

Tags: audio, iphone

I'm trying to emulate via Arduino the `volume down` button of the remote mounted on iphone earbuds, and I can't find anywhere how that function is achieved; I imagine that certain passive components housed in the earbuds are shorted to the mic-gnd TRRS pins (upper ring and sleeve), but I can't really figure which ones.

Thanks.

Comment: Related:  [How do volume control headphones work?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38417/how-do-volume-control-headphones-work) and  [4 pin headset pinout / pushbuttons interface](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96156/4-pin-headset-pinout-pushbuttons-interface)

Answer (score 1):

I found [this form](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=841431) to have some answers. It looks like pressing different buttons shorts the signal pin and ground with different resistor values. In [this diagram](http://cdn.head-fi.org/a/af/af5786d7_head-fi.jpeg), that would be pin 3 for GND and pin 4 for signal.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://tinymicros.com/wiki/Apple_iPod_Remote_Protocol) the volume buttons are connected to a little IC inside the remote.  It's a little more complicated than you'd expect, using little chirps instead of just passives.

Comment: That's the shuffle 3g remote,  not the iPhone remote. Not the same.

Comment: And in which way is it different?  The iphone headphones are listed as compatible with the headless version of the shuffle on their website.